# How to plot summaries of timestamps of different projects clocking in and out?

Tags: org-mode

I've searched extensively online but have not found an easy solution. Maybe there is already an easy solution or some tips on doing this easily?

I am clocking in the amount of time I spend on different projects. I can summarize the clocktable using `org-clock-report`. However, I would like to visualize this data using either barplots for different projects (easiest), or a breakdown of how much time I spend on different projects as a function of the calendar year (most complicated).

Has anyone already tried this? Is there an easy way to parse the timestamps into a file format that makes it easy to plot in standard software such as excel or R?

Example org file:

```
*** Analysis
    CLOCK: [2016-06-06 Mon 21:13]--[2016-06-06 Mon 22:29] =>  1:16
    CLOCK: [2016-06-06 Mon 14:20]--[2016-06-06 Mon 17:31] =>  3:11
    CLOCK: [2016-06-06 Mon 09:50]--[2016-06-06 Mon 12:15] =>  2:25

*** Meeting
    CLOCK: [2016-06-07 Tue 09:07]--[2016-06-07 Tue 11:46] =>  2:39
    CLOCK: [2016-06-06 Mon 13:43]--[2016-06-06 Mon 14:20] =>  0:37
```

The idea would be to wrangle these timestamps into a file format that would be easily amenable to plotting (excel or R).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [Org Element API](http://orgmode.org/worg/dev/org-element-api.html) enables you to create an AST from an Org buffer. There are two options I know of to make use of it: Either create a JSON file as described in [this gist](https://gist.github.com/donlindsay/829d5ffb059aca232261) and proceed in your preferred language, or filter the elements of interest in Emacs Lisp using Org-babel blocks and Org-table. Assuming I am in your example buffer:

```
#+begin_src elisp :results table
(nconc
 '(("month" "day" "clockin" "clockout" "duration" "status" "title"))
 '(hline)
 (let ((ast (org-element-parse-buffer 'element)))
   (org-element-map ast 'clock
     (lambda (x)
       (let ((val (org-element-property :value x)))
     `(,(calendar-month-name (org-element-property :month-start val) t)
       ,(number-to-string (org-element-property :day-start val))
       ,(concat (number-to-string (org-element-property :hour-start val))
            ":"
            (format "%02d" (org-element-property :minute-start val)))
       ,(concat (number-to-string (org-element-property :hour-end val))
            ":"
            (format "%02d" (org-element-property :minute-end val)))
       ,(org-element-property :duration x)
       ,(org-element-property :status x)
       ,@(org-element-map
         (org-element-property :parent (org-element-property :parent x))
         'headline
           (lambda (x) (org-element-property :title x)))))))))
#+end_src

#+results:
| month | day | clockin | clockout | duration | status | title    |
|-------+-----+---------+----------+----------+--------+----------|
| Jun   |   6 |   21:13 |    22:29 |     1:16 | closed | Analysis |
| Jun   |   6 |   14:20 |    17:31 |     3:11 | closed | Analysis |
| Jun   |   6 |    9:50 |    12:15 |     2:25 | closed | Analysis |
| Jun   |   7 |    9:07 |    11:46 |     2:39 | closed | Meeting  |
| Jun   |   6 |   13:43 |    14:20 |     0:37 | closed | Meeting  |
```

To refer to another Org buffer, wrap the code with `(with-current-buffer BUFFER ...)`.

Comment: Great! This works. Thanks for all your help.